# Getting JMeter to work with Throughput Shaping timer and Concurrency Thread Group

Tags: timer, concurrency, jmeter

I am trying to shape a JMeter test involving a `Concurrency Thread Group` and a `Throughput Shaping Timer` as documented [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer) and [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/). the timer is configured to run ten ramps and stages with RPS from 1 to 333.
I want to set up the Concurrency Thread Group to use the [schedule feedback function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) and added the formula in the Target concurrency field (I have updated the example from tst-name to the actual timer name). ramp-up time and steps I have set to 1 as I assume the properties are not that important if the throughput is managed by the timer; the Hold Target Rate time is 8000, which is longer than the steps added in the timer (6200).

When I run the test, it ends without any exceptions within 3 seconds or so. The log file shows a few rows about starting and ending threads but nothing alarming.
The only thing I find suspicious is the Log entry `"VirtualUserController: Test limit reached, thread is done` plus thread name.

I am not getting enough clues from the documentation linked here to figure this out myself, do you have any hints?

Comment: As a beginner, I followed https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) rampup time and steps should be *blank*:

> When using this approach, leave Concurrency Thread Group Ramp Up Time and Ramp-Up Steps Count fields blank"

So your assumption that setting them to 1 is OK, seems false...